# How to prevent duplication of JIRA Tickets in python

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, python-jira

I have 2 instances of JIRA . I have written a script where tickets from one instance are read and a replicas of same are created in another instance.

Now the problem is , whenever I run the script it is generating duplicate tickets again and again.

How do I prevent this duplication of tickets? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1. Create a link field in each Jira issue and populate it. If the field is populated the script should not create a new issue
2. Use a "last synced" field in the source Jira and only create a new issue if the source issue has not been synced

You don't say but I assumed that this is a one way sync